# Node.js Swagger generate UI doc JSON feed

Tags: node.js, swagger

I'm using Node.js and Swagger to build a restful API. The Swagger UI (demo link here http://petstore.swagger.io/) requires a JSON feed.

How would you generate this feed based on the Swagger spec yaml file? Is there not a npm module that can iterate over the yaml file and generate the JSON feed? I'm new to Swagger so I might have overlooked something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swagger UI should support YAML by now. You can convert YAML to JSON using [JSYAML](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) library.

Comment: You are absolutely correct Mohsen! I have tested this right now on localhost and Swagger UI does indeed support a well formatted Swagger spec file straight out of the box. Both yaml and json are supported so no conversion needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Swagger Editor:

http://editor.swagger.io/#/

I can't say I have tried it before, but you can upload YAML and export as YAML or JSON.

I have used the editor before and do really like it.

EDIT:

So to setup the swagger ui I did the following:

```
var swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
  url:"http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
  dom_id:"swagger-ui-container"
});

swaggerUi.load();
```

That comes from here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

I think you got that part.

As for the doc (YAML or JSON) just serve it out from your site.  If you are using express with your nodejs server just serve out the file statically:

http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
```

So in this case if you put the swagger.json file right under your public dir you can access it with:

```
http://<yoursite>/swagger.json
```

Just test that you can actually get to your swagger docs from that url in the browser.  Put that URL into the 'url' parameter above when you setup swagger-ui and you should be go to go.  Swagger-ui will do the rest for you, it will pull the json or yaml definition from your site and generate the interactive docs site.

Comment: I understand how the Swagger UI works, but how do you generate the JSON feed that goes into Swagger UI? I'm looking for some Node middleware that parses the Swagger yaml / json file and generates the UI docs feed

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sorry I was confused.  I can update the answer to see if that helps.

Comment: I was over engineering things. You don't need any middleware. Swagger UI can work directly with the Swagger spec file in either yaml or json.

Comment: I tried to do that. I stuck on the level of importing swagger-ui in my app
    
     var swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
          url:"http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
          dom_id:"swagger-ui-container"
        });
        swaggerUi.load();
    
I got an error saying that SwaggerUi is not defined !!!
Any help ?